# Using Vue.js transitions to show content but only letting the transition happen once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have used the Vue.js documentation linked below to created the show transition, how would I stop the hide on the second click?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#a

Will I be able to use this transition or another method, I have tried using .once to try and stop a second occurrence.

I have also tried creating a method using:

```
v-on:change.once="animate()"
```

and the method:

```
    animate: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.show = true;
    },
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but like you suggested, I tried `@click.once` in following code and then transition happen only once:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click.once="switc = !switc">
  <span>Switch</span>
</button>
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa5fmers/): `Switch` button allows transition only once.